# How do i make my progress dialog dismiss after webview is loaded?

Tags: java, android, webview, progressdialog, dismiss

What do I need to my code to make the dialog `dismiss()` after the webview is loaded?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            setContentView(R.layout.main); 
            CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
            webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new homeClient());
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
            webview.loadUrl("http://google.com");

            ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "", 
                    "Loading. Please wait...", true);

        }
```

I've tried

```
public void onPageFinshed(WebView view, String url){
        pd.dismiss();
    }
```

Didn't work.

Comment: Is onPageFinished called?  In the ui thread?

Comment: Sorry I should have just done this in the first place, i put the whole Class up the way i current have it. and if you scroll up you can see I tried a onPageFinshed and it didnt work. maybe the way I did it was wrong? or where I placed it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

:o
webview.setWebViewClient(new homeClient());  **homeClient()**????

try this

```
...
...
...

webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }


          public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }
 webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

}
```

**Update::**
this is a good example.

[Android WebView and the Indeterminant Progress Solution](http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2010/05/04/android-webview-and-the-indeterminant-progress-solution/)

Answer (score 3):

This is OK.

```
public class WordActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webview;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        Bundle objetbunble  = this.getIntent().getExtras(); 
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        final Activity activity = this;

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Chargement en cours");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            }
        }); 
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    }


}
```

Comment: Hey samuel i have used ur code for webviews for initial launch every thing working fine. so when i navigate to same webview for second time progressdialog showing continously after pagefinish(note:waited for 10mins but progress dialog did not dismiss) Please help me how can i do tat.. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

@Jorgesys this is not 100% accurate. If you have several iframes in a page you will have multiple onPageFinished (and onPageStarted). And if you have several redirects it may also fail. This approach i think solves all the problems:

```
boolean loadingFinished = true;
boolean redirect = false;

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
       if (!loadingFinished) {
          redirect = true;
       }

   loadingFinished = false;
   webView.loadUrl(urlNewString);
   return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url) {
        loadingFinished = false;
        //SHOW LOADING IF IT ISNT ALREADY VISIBLE  
    }

   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       if(!redirect){
          loadingFinished = true;
       }

       if(loadingFinished && !redirect){
         //HIDE LOADING IT HAS FINISHED
       } else{
          redirect = false; 
       }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you accessing `pd` in `onPageFinshed()`? (And are you sure it's actually called when the page loads?)

In your `onCreate()`, try passing `pd` to your `homeClient` so that `homeClient` can take care of dismissing the dialog.

Your homeClient should look like this:

```
private class homeClient extends WebViewClient {

    private ProgressDialog pd;

    public homeClient(ProgressDialog pd) {
        this.pd = pd;
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {           
        view.loadUrl(url); 
        return true; 
    } 

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

In your `onCreate()`:

```
ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(Fbook.this, "", 
                "Loading. Please wait...", true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new homeClient(pd));
```

Comment: Very nice example, i like it!

Comment: Cool...the part I've been missing for minutes now.

Answer (score 0):

> If you simply want to show Progress before webPage loading in WebView. You can simply request for **Window Feature Progress** like

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

before `setContentView(R.layout.blahblah);`

and show it progress in onProgressChanged like

```
 final Activity context= this;
 webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 
 {
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView webView, int progress) 
   {
     activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
   }
 });
```

And if you want to add you own **ProgressDialog then use WebviewClient**

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    ProgressDialog rogressDialog ;
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading...", "Please wait...");//where context = YourActivity.this;
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        progressDialog .dismiss();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
});

webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(Entertainment.this, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
            {
                progressDialog.show();
            }


            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                String webUrl = wv1.getUrl();

            }

        });

    wv1.loadUrl(url);
```

The above code will show a progress dialogue for every incoming link you navigate to the in webview.