# ProgressDialogue box not appearing in webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I am just stuck at a little thing for about 1 full day I created a **webview android** app and its working fine but i want a progress dialogue box which basically appears when the next page loads. here is my code

```
//ProgressDialogue
    ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Please Wait..");
        pd.setMessage("Your Internet is Slow..");
        pd.show();
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        pd.dismiss();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
```

Please help me fix this and tell me the error 
**and i did imported *android.app.ProgressDialog;***

Comment: Solved this yet ??

Comment: @intellij not yet

Answer (score 0):

```
  ProgressDialog pd; //Global
  pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); // OnCreate
        pd.setTitle("Please Wait..");
        pd.setMessage("Your Internet is Slow..");


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);  // Should be First
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url); //Should be First 
        pd.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Definitely better but I doubt that will solve this guy's issue.

Comment: still not getting the progressdialog box

Comment: @SkylineGeek go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849347/adding-a-progress-dialog-in-a-webview

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i tried every possible step but still i am not getting that dialog box. If you want i can give you the whole java file

Comment: @SkylineGeek Okay . Create a dummy project and add single webview with ProgressDialog.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya will removing the waste webview solve this