# progress bar in webview keeps loading not hiding after page finished loading

Tags: android, android-webview, android-progressbar

I am showing a progress dialog in my webview 
but it is not hiding on page finished
i browsed through many SO its said to "progress.dismiss()" 
but still its not dismissing
also the loading is not shown which i move to other pages in the webview

my code is

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private WebView webView;
private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
ConnectivityManager cm;
android.net.NetworkInfo wifi;
android.net.NetworkInfo datac;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    datac = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if ((wifi != null & datac != null)
            && (wifi.isConnected() | datac.isConnected())) {
        //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  //to hide notification bar
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                boolean returnValue=true;
                if ((wifi != null & datac != null)
                        && (wifi.isConnected() | datac.isConnected())) {
                    if ((Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("www.cbazaar") || Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("payseal.icicibank")) || Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("www.ccavenue")
                            || Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("www.braintreepaments") || Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("www.sandbox")) {

                        returnValue=false;
                    }

                if(returnValue==true){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return returnValue;
                }
                }
                return returnValue;
            }
         @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                      String description, String failingUrl) {
             webView.loadUrl("javascript:history.go(-1)");

          }
            ProgressDialog pd = null;

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pd.setTitle("Please wait");
                pd.setMessage("");
                pd.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.cbazaar.com");
    }else{
        //no connection
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_no_internet);
        Button netOnBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.netOnButton);
        Button refreshHmeBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.refreshHmeBtn);
        netOnBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
            }
        });
        refreshHmeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent gotoMainActivity = new Intent (MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(gotoMainActivity);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
// Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

@Override
// Detect when the back button is pressed
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        // Let the system handle the back button
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Can some one help me as how can this be debugged or why is the loading not dismissing and not displaying when moving to other pages

Thanks in advance as this is my first web app.

Comment: Try : `progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this,"Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);` in `onLoadResource` without if clause and ` progressDialog.dismiss();` in `onPageFinished()` without if clause

Comment: try2: `progressDialog.cancel();`

Comment: sorry even this dint seem to work it keeps loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void startWebView(String url) {

    MyView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress < 100) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this

                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();

            }

            if (progress == 100) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            }
        }
    });


    // Javascript enabled on webview
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //Load url in webview
    webView.loadUrl(url);

}
```

This way, you can use a real progressbar in your ProgressDialog.

Comment: Thanks for the help it some what helped but this is opening multiple progress dialog one above other and all of it keeps loading

Comment: i am having an error in @Override

"Method does not override method from its superclass"


Also in your previous code the multiple progress dialog happend because the page im loading at first gets redirected from cbazaar.com to cbazaar.in

After which the loading worked fine

Comment: Hi @JonasCz i have updated my code kindly check it 
if i put your code the above mentioned error is shown

Also do let me know if my code is properly structured

Comment: i didnt have a chrome client 
that was the issue
but on having chromeclient the app is getting crashed on showing the loading

Comment: Hi did u i still couldn't find a way to solve this . Did u get any idea.

Comment: @jalilIrfan, Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3993002/4428462). there are also many results on google if you search for "progessdialog webview". I'm quite busy so I can't try code now.