# why the progress dialog doesn't disappear on some page?

Tags: java, android

this is my mainactivity, when i load some page the progress dialog doesn't disappear onpagefinished...where is the problem?
if you want to try the problem are with the page "accedi" or on the payment of the order

```
private WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);


    webView.setClickable(true);
    webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.alldrink.it");
    WebClientClass webViewClient = new WebClientClass();
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    WebChromeClient webChromeClient=new WebChromeClient();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
    setContentView(webView);
    webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });


}



public class WebClientClass extends WebViewClient {
    ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Attendere");
        pd.setMessage("Caricamento in corso..");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();

        }
    }


}




public class WebChromeClass extends WebChromeClient{

}
```

}

Comment: the dismiss() function is working, but your onPageStarted() has run two times, making dialog recreate again and look like it never disappear.

Comment: As it says in this answer, if you have several iframes in a page you will have multiple onPageFinished (and onPageStarted). And if you have several redirects it may also fail. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5172983/2091181

Answer (score 0):

the dismiss() function is working, but your onPageStarted() has run two times, making dialog recreate again and look like it never disappear. Try changing your `onPageStarted` as:

```
@Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        if(!pd.isShowing())
        {
            pd.setTitle("Attendere");
            pd.setMessage("Caricamento in corso..");
            pd.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i try to past this code but the app doesn't start, if i put (pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);) inside the if i have the same problem of before...:(

Comment: When I tried running your code last time, I only put `ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);` between/inside `WebClientClass` and (outside) `onPageStarted`, and it's working